# Django generic views - sending data to project templates

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

i try to send data with generic views from my app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'*', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")[:2],
    template_name="/mysite/templates/index.html"
    )),
)
```

however, data cannot be sent
i c/p this query and result is returned. What's missing?

in mysite/templates/index.html

```
 {% for post in object_list %}
     {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
```

prints nothing

Comment: there's no error . i think data does not go to mysite/templates/index.html . I try to send data from blog app's urls.py

Comment: Did you add the app to INSTALLED_APPS? Are there actually Post objects?

Comment: Yeap there is a line called     "blog",
    in my settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 2):

You are not providing enough information. `r'*'` is not a valid regular expression - `*` needs something to act on - and Django would report that if you tried to use it in a URLconf. You need to show how you are including that url in your main urls.py.

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")[:2],
 template_name="/mysite/templates/index.html"
    )),
) i edited like that  and     url(r"^blog/", include('blog.urls')), in urls.py of main project

Comment: OK, so now what happens when you browse to `/blog`?

Comment: /mysite/templates/index.html, blog/post_list.html
 template does not exists but how can i change to blog/post_list.html to  templates/index.html

Comment: one more question What's the right way ? Do i have to start an app named blog or directly create a model in project base ?

Comment: I'm sorry, you seem to be asking random questions now. Please read your way all through the Django tutorial, and if there's still things you don't understand open a new question.

Comment: /mysite/templates/index.html, blog/post_list.html template does not exists but how can i change to blog/post_list.html to templates/index.html